# What's the negative assertion of this regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match the following:

- This:

  ```
  HIGH SCHOOL WRESTLING NOTEBOOK: A surge at Delaware Valley, team rankings shakeup and more.
  ```
- With This :

  ```
  <pre>
    <div class="sum">
      <div class="photo_gutter">
        <div class="photo">
          <a href="http://media.lehighvalleylive.com/brad-wilson/photo/jaryd-flank-b30e919c41bc86b2.jpg">
            <img src="http://media.lehighvalleylive.com/brad-wilson/photo/jaryd-flank-b30e919c41bc86b2.jpg" alt="" title="" width="200" border="0"/>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    HIGH SCHOOL WRESTLING NOTEBOOK: A surge at Delaware Valley, team rankings shakeup and more.
  </pre>
  ```

What I have so far is `/<.*>\s/i`, but I need the opposite of that. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use regex to parse HTML, use [PHP Domdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.

Comment: It's part of some RSS that I have to parse. From what I know, their's no other way to do that.

Comment: There is. Try SimplePie to parse RSS, and Domdocument to parse that HTML

Comment: @user2039132 - can you explain further why it being an RSS feed requires a regex to parse it? Parsing (X)HTML with regexs gets complicated very quickly, whereas all the hard work in done for you in an HTML parser.

Comment: The RSS feed that I'm using is from my local newspapers' website, it's pretty much just HTML in almost every XML NameSpaces. It's highly annoying and I don't know of any other way of making it work without using this negative RegEx. I just want to echo what I want to match and that's it, I don't want 3 billion lines of code. This is for something for school, it doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: @user2039132 with SimplePie and DomDocument, that would be 30 lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, with a class script that I don't want. Can someone please just give me the negative assertion of the RegEx please?

Comment: @user2039132 Then do not use SimplePie, use SimpleXML and DomDocument, both are not Class scripts, but builtin PHP functions.
The regex solution will break in more ways than you can fix.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use regex to parse HTML, but since it's a simple task (and probably meant to learn regex):

You have this: `/<.*>\s/i`

1- The `i` modifier does nothing here, since you are not using any character that could be case sensitive in the regex expression. i.e: `/apple/i` makes sense cause you want to find `Apple`. `/\w+/i` does nothing since `\w` includes both lowercase and uppercase characters.

2- If you are parsing HTML it's better to don't assume or use any `\s` unless you are inside of a tag.

3- If you want to capture a part of the regex into a variable you have to use `(` and `)`. i.e: `/(\w+) Apple/` parsing `Red Apple` would give you `Red` in `$1` or in the array of matches of the `preg_match()` function.

Now how would I do this:

First of all, I would remove any `\r\n` or `\n` from the input string. Regex works much better with only 1 line of text. You can do this with a `str_replace()`

If you want to get anything that is not inside `<>`:

`/>(.*?)</`

If you want to get the text inside of a certain tag, for example `<div>this one</div>`:

`/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/`

The `?` character makes the `.*` match to be non-greedy, so It will get the least number of characters that match the pattern.

Hope it helped.

Comment: `/<.*>\s/i` <-- Have you tested this one? It will eat up a lot of things. Not sure how it would fit into the context here. `/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/` <-- Since div can contain div, and the regex cannot do bracket balancing, you will get weird thing out of it.